# How do I expand/collapse a data group in excel with HYPERLINK function

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I have an excel that has 2 worksheets. The Sheet1 contains the HYPERLINK to go Sheet2 which has data that is group together.  I want to expand the data group(sheet2) once I click the link to sheet2. After expanding the group, I want to collapse them back when I leave the Sheet2. Here is my formula for the HYPERLINK in Sheet1

[image]

And here is my data group Sheet2.
[image]

I am not good in excel nor in VBA.

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you open to vba solution?

Comment: Yes, I am open to VBA solution. I think this is the only way to run this on a macro. I am not familiar with VBA but I could learn from it.  Thank you for looking into this.

Comment: Just to be sure, why are you using the hyperlink function? using just a regular hyperlink would make things easier.

Comment: The reason I am using the Hyperlink function rather than a regular hyperlink because if I need to change the cell address of each, I need to manually edit the regular hyperlink. I have experienced this in the past. It's a lot of work on my end. The screen shot that I have provided is just a small data and I am going to work with large data group that I may need to insert more. In addition I would like to toggle between Sheet1 and Sheet2 using the hyperlink function for each cell. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using the Hyperlink function and it doesn't fire the followhyperlink event, this is my workaround:

I. Add a module to store a global variable to track what was the last selection before activating sheet2

Steps

1) Add a module

2) Paste the following code:

```
Option Explicit

' Variable to track last selected cell    
Global selectedCell As Range
```

This is how it should look like this:

[image]

II. Set the variable to the last selected cell in Sheet1

Steps:

1) Double click Sheet1 object

2) Add the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    ' Track last selected cell
    Set selectedCell = Target

End Sub
```

This is how it should look like this:

[image]

III. In Sheet2 test to see if the last selected cell address comes from Sheet1 and is in an specific range, and if it does, expand the collpased details

Steps:

1) Double click Sheet2 object

2) Add the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

On Error GoTo Err_handler

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' Check if selectedCell is already set if not, stop processing
    If selectedCell Is Nothing Then
        Sheet1.Activate
        Set selectedCell = Selection
        Sheet2.Activate
    End If

    ' Check if previous cell is "Sheet1!$B$4"
    If selectedCell.Parent.Name & "!" & selectedCell.Address = "Sheet1!$B$4" Then

        ' <<<< Customize the row where the grouped rows begins and are visible
        ' (this row depends whether you have "Summary rows below detail" active or not if it's not active, you have to use the next visible row) >>>>
        With Sheet2.Rows(1)
            .ShowDetail = Not .ShowDetail
        End With

    End If

Exit_Sub:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

Err_handler:
    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
    Resume Exit_Sub

End Sub
```

IV. When Sheet2 deactivates collapse the details

Steps:

1) Locate the cursos at the end of Sheet2 code

2) Add the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()

    ' <<<Customize Sheet2 to the Name of your worksheet>>>

    ' Collapse all rows that are grouped
    Sheet2.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=1

End Sub
```

Sheet2 code should look like this:

[image]

Complete Sheet2 code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

On Error GoTo Err_handler

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' Check if selectedCell is already set if not, stop processing
    If selectedCell Is Nothing Then
        Sheet1.Activate
        Set selectedCell = Selection
        Sheet2.Activate
    End If

    ' Check if previous cell is "Sheet1!$B$4"
    If selectedCell.Parent.Name & "!" & selectedCell.Address = "Sheet1!$B$4" Then

        ' <<<< Customize the row where the grouped rows begins and are visible >>>>
        ' (this row depends whether you have "Summary rows below detail" active or not if it's not active, you have to use the next visible row) >>>>
        With Sheet2.Rows(1)
            .ShowDetail = Not .ShowDetail
        End With

    End If

Exit_Sub:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

Err_handler:
    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume Exit_Sub

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()

    ' <<<Customize Sheet2 to the Name of your worksheet>>>

    ' Collapse all rows that are grouped
    Sheet2.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=1

End Sub
```

Give it a try and let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your time.  I am getting an error.  Run time error '1004': Unable to set ShowDetail property of the Range class. Sorry I was trying to include a screen shot here in my comment but I was having issue using the paste.

Comment: Check if last grouped row is number 12. I based my answer on your screenshot.

Comment: I assumed you wanted to collapse/expand first group in sheet2. If you want to do it on all groups. I’d have to adjust that part of the code

Comment: The screenshot that I have provided is wrong it should go to Cell A2(Test1) of Sheet2 and not A14(Test11) of Sheet 2 as indicated. The Cell A14(Test11)  Sheet2 should be coming from Cell B5(Tes11) of Sheet1.  So if I select Test1 from Sheet1, I need to expand the TestA group only of Sheet2. Once I leave Sheet2, all groups should be collapsed. Thank you

Comment: You can edit your own question and paste the correct screenshot

Comment: I have updated my question with the correct screenshot. Thank you

Comment: I have updated the code for collapsing all grouped rows in sheet2. Look for '<<< Customize >>> fragments in order to see what you have to customize in the code to make it work.

As for this: The screenshot that I have provided is wrong it should go to Cell A2(Test1) of Sheet2 and not A14(Test11) of Sheet 2 as indicated. The Cell A14(Test11) Sheet2 should be coming from Cell B5(Tes11) of Sheet1 it isn't clear for me. I couldn't identify what changed in your screenshot

Comment: I'm sorry about that if this is not clear to you. Is there a way I could attach my excel in this question?  I've customized the code but I am getting the error of Runtime error '91' Object Variable or With block variable not set. Thanks

Comment: Paste here the link to the file. You can share it through onedrive, google drive or any other major file sharing service provider.

Comment: I have updated the code. As you had a setting for not showing the details below the grouped rows, I had to use Row 1 in order to expand the grouped rows.

Comment: This is really good. I am getting what I need. The Test1 group that I selected is being expanded in Sheet2. However when I go to Sheet1 and back to Sheet2 without clicking the Test1 from Sheet1. The Test1 group is still expanded in Sheet2. I was expecting it to be collapsed if I don't select the Test1 hyperlink from Sheet1. Also, is there a way not to hard code the value of the selectedCell.Address in the VBA code in Sheet2. Because I may have more groups in this Excel. Right now I only have 2 groups and your VBA code is only working for TestA group and not TestB group. Thank you for your time

Comment: The solution is a workaround as the followhyperlink event is not fired when you use the hyperlink function.

Comment: I will try this work around and see where it goes on my excel. Thank you very much for your time.At least I have a good start and understanding on my question. Have a great day!

Comment: Great. As it helped you, please consider marking it as answered